# Laravel 5.5. Сгенерировать query string формата /smth-str/val1/val2

Tags: php, laravel, request

Как проще всего сгенерировать URL такого вида:

`/smth-str/val1/val2` ?

`request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['par1'=>'val1', 'par2'=>'val2'])`
генерирует

`/?par1=val1&par2=val2`, а нужно `/val1/val2` (без имени параметра).

Уже несколько часов мучаюсь, буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$par = ['par1'=>'val1', 'par2'=>'val2'];
$url = $request->url().implode('/',$par);
```

Или если используете роуты с именем:

```
Route::get('smth-str/{par1}/{par2}', function ($par1,$par2) {
    //
})->name('smth');

 $par = ['par1'=>'val1', 'par2'=>'val2';
$url = route('smth', $par);
```